# R Intersection of list with itself

Tags: r, unique, intersection

I have a list called my_list which contains a name of a store and IDs of all customers who bought something. What I want is a list of "shared" customers, some list which would look like:
store1, store2, intersection of customers of store1 and store2.

I did write:

```
my_list2<-lapply(my_list, function(x) lapply(my_list, function(y) intersect(x[[1]],y[[1]])))
```

which works. 
BUT I would like to have only unique combination of stores, that means I would like to have only

```
(store1,store2,shared customers)
```

and not

```
(store2,store1,shared customers).
```

Also I do not want

```
(store1, store1, shared customers),
```

this gives me only a list of all customers who bought from store1.

And last, in my_list2 I would like to have only those lines, where stores have at least one shared customer, so no empty intersection.

Could you help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll have to provide some example data to get an answer for this.

Comment: `combn` could probably work with some sort of anonymous function.

Comment: I would like to avoid a loop since it takes a lot of time (I have a 4GB data file) and this lapply works faster

Comment: @A.S - `lapply` is a loop. And we still need some small, representative example data to figure out exactly what you want.

Comment: So lets say I have a list: 
(store1, cust1, cust2, cust3),  
(store2, cust1, cust4),
(store3, cust4)
What I want is: (store1$store2, cust1), (store2$store3, cust4), so no duplicities like (store2$store1, cust1) and no empty intersections like (store1$store3, ())

Answer (score 1):

If you loop across the indices in the list, and only compute intersections with `x[[i]]`, `y[[j]]`, such that `i < j`, you won't have duplicates.  Note it is still n choose 2 `intersect`s, and hence still O(n^2 * intersect) complexity.
Looping across the indices could look like the following

```
my_list <- list(a=1:10,b=5:14)
len <- length(my_list)

lapply(1:(len-1), function(i) 
    lapply((i+1):len, function(j) intersect(my_list[[i]], my_list[[j]])))
```

Comment: Thanks, I did something like this, but I really do not want lines in list with empty intersect, do you know how to do that?